# Sage does not recognize a unit ideal

Tags: sage

I am trying to learn a bit of sage and I have tried playing with ideals in p-adic rings. But I don't understand how ideals work in polynomial rings. I have tried writing the following

```
A=Zp(5)
R.<x>=A[]
g1=(1+x)^(25)-1;
g2=6^(-25)*((1+x)^(25)-6^(25));
J=R.ideal(37,g1)
I=R.ideal(37,g2)
U=R.unit_ideal();
I==U
I==J
J==U
```

Since 37 is a 5-adic unit, I would expect the answer to be

```
True
True
True
```

because both I and J contain 37. But it is

```
False
False
False
```

What am I missing? I also apologise for not being able to understand how to TeX in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently Sage isn't checking that automatically.

```
print(U)
print(I)
print(J)
Principal ideal (1 + O(5^20)) of Univariate Polynomial Ring in x over 5-adic Ring with capped relative precision 20
Ideal (2 + 2*5 + 5^2 + O(5^20), (1 + 4*5^3 + 2*5^4 + 4*5^7 + 2*5^8 + 3*5^9 + 3*5^10 + 3*5^12 + 5^13 + 4*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 5^18 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^25 + (5^2 + 4*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 4*5^9 + 2*5^10 + 3*5^11 + 3*5^12 + 3*5^14 + 5^15 + 4*5^17 + 4*5^18 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^24 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 3*5^5 + 3*5^6 + 5^7 + 5^8 + 3*5^9 + 3*5^10 + 2*5^11 + 4*5^12 + 3*5^13 + 2*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 3*5^16 + 3*5^17 + 2*5^18 + O(5^20))*x^23 + (2*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 5^7 + 3*5^10 + 2*5^11 + 5^12 + 3*5^13 + 4*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 3*5^17 + 2*5^18 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^22 + (5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 5^8 + 4*5^10 + 5^11 + 3*5^12 + 3*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 5^17 + 4*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^21 + (5 + 4*5^4 + 4*5^5 + 3*5^6 + 2*5^8 + 3*5^10 + 4*5^12 + 2*5^14 + 3*5^15 + 5^16 + 3*5^17 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^20 + (4*5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^4 + 2*5^5 + 5^6 + 4*5^7 + 3*5^8 + 4*5^9 + 5^10 + 2*5^12 + 4*5^13 + 3*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 3*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^19 + (3*5^2 + 4*5^4 + 4*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 4*5^8 + 2*5^9 + 4*5^10 + 3*5^11 + 2*5^12 + 4*5^14 + 2*5^16 + O(5^20))*x^18 + (3*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 3*5^5 + 5^7 + 3*5^8 + 5^9 + 3*5^14 + 5^16 + 2*5^17 + 5^18 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^17 + (4*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + 4*5^5 + 3*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 2*5^8 + 2*5^9 + 4*5^10 + 2*5^11 + 5^13 + 5^14 + 2*5^15 + 3*5^17 + 5^18 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^16 + (2*5 + 3*5^4 + 5^5 + 2*5^7 + 5^9 + 3*5^10 + 4*5^11 + 3*5^12 + 4*5^13 + 2*5^14 + 3*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 4*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^15 + (5^2 + 4*5^3 + 5^4 + 4*5^6 + 2*5^7 + 3*5^10 + 3*5^11 + 5^12 + 3*5^13 + 2*5^14 + 3*5^15 + 3*5^16 + 5^17 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^14 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 2*5^5 + 5^6 + 3*5^7 + 5^10 + 4*5^11 + 2*5^12 + 3*5^14 + 5^15 + 4*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 4*5^18 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^13 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 2*5^5 + 5^6 + 3*5^7 + 5^10 + 4*5^11 + 2*5^12 + 3*5^14 + 5^15 + 4*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 4*5^18 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^12 + (5^2 + 4*5^3 + 5^4 + 4*5^6 + 2*5^7 + 3*5^10 + 3*5^11 + 5^12 + 3*5^13 + 2*5^14 + 3*5^15 + 3*5^16 + 5^17 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^11 + (2*5 + 3*5^4 + 5^5 + 2*5^7 + 5^9 + 3*5^10 + 4*5^11 + 3*5^12 + 4*5^13 + 2*5^14 + 3*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 4*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^10 + (4*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + 4*5^5 + 3*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 2*5^8 + 2*5^9 + 4*5^10 + 2*5^11 + 5^13 + 5^14 + 2*5^15 + 3*5^17 + 5^18 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^9 + (3*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 3*5^5 + 5^7 + 3*5^8 + 5^9 + 3*5^14 + 5^16 + 2*5^17 + 5^18 + 5^19 + O(5^20))*x^8 + (3*5^2 + 4*5^4 + 4*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 4*5^8 + 2*5^9 + 4*5^10 + 3*5^11 + 2*5^12 + 4*5^14 + 2*5^16 + O(5^20))*x^7 + (4*5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^4 + 2*5^5 + 5^6 + 4*5^7 + 3*5^8 + 4*5^9 + 5^10 + 2*5^12 + 4*5^13 + 3*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 3*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^6 + (5 + 4*5^4 + 4*5^5 + 3*5^6 + 2*5^8 + 3*5^10 + 4*5^12 + 2*5^14 + 3*5^15 + 5^16 + 3*5^17 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^5 + (5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 5^8 + 4*5^10 + 5^11 + 3*5^12 + 3*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 5^17 + 4*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^4 + (2*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 5^7 + 3*5^10 + 2*5^11 + 5^12 + 3*5^13 + 4*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 3*5^17 + 2*5^18 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x^3 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 3*5^5 + 3*5^6 + 5^7 + 5^8 + 3*5^9 + 3*5^10 + 2*5^11 + 4*5^12 + 3*5^13 + 2*5^14 + 4*5^15 + 3*5^16 + 3*5^17 + 2*5^18 + O(5^20))*x^2 + (5^2 + 4*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 4*5^9 + 2*5^10 + 3*5^11 + 3*5^12 + 3*5^14 + 5^15 + 4*5^17 + 4*5^18 + 2*5^19 + O(5^20))*x + 4*5^3 + 2*5^4 + 4*5^7 + 2*5^8 + 3*5^9 + 3*5^10 + 3*5^12 + 5^13 + 4*5^15 + 4*5^16 + 2*5^17 + 5^18 + 5^19 + O(5^20)) of Univariate Polynomial Ring in x over 5-adic Ring with capped relative precision 20
Ideal (2 + 2*5 + 5^2 + O(5^20), (1 + O(5^20))*x^25 + (5^2 + O(5^20))*x^24 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + O(5^20))*x^23 + (2*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + O(5^20))*x^22 + (5^2 + 5^3 + 4*5^5 + O(5^20))*x^21 + (5 + 2*5^5 + 3*5^6 + O(5^20))*x^20 + (4*5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^4 + 5^5 + 5^6 + 2*5^7 + O(5^20))*x^19 + (3*5^2 + 4*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 5^7 + 5^8 + O(5^20))*x^18 + (3*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 5^5 + 4*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 2*5^8 + O(5^20))*x^17 + (4*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 5^7 + 5^9 + O(5^20))*x^16 + (2*5 + 5^5 + 4*5^6 + 5^7 + 3*5^8 + 5^9 + O(5^20))*x^15 + (5^2 + 4*5^3 + 5^4 + 5^5 + 2*5^7 + 5^8 + 2*5^9 + O(5^20))*x^14 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 4*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 5^7 + 3*5^8 + 2*5^9 + O(5^20))*x^13 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 4*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 5^7 + 3*5^8 + 2*5^9 + O(5^20))*x^12 + (5^2 + 4*5^3 + 5^4 + 5^5 + 2*5^7 + 5^8 + 2*5^9 + O(5^20))*x^11 + (2*5 + 5^5 + 4*5^6 + 5^7 + 3*5^8 + 5^9 + O(5^20))*x^10 + (4*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 5^7 + 5^9 + O(5^20))*x^9 + (3*5^2 + 2*5^3 + 5^5 + 4*5^6 + 3*5^7 + 2*5^8 + O(5^20))*x^8 + (3*5^2 + 4*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 5^7 + 5^8 + O(5^20))*x^7 + (4*5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^4 + 5^5 + 5^6 + 2*5^7 + O(5^20))*x^6 + (5 + 2*5^5 + 3*5^6 + O(5^20))*x^5 + (5^2 + 5^3 + 4*5^5 + O(5^20))*x^4 + (2*5^2 + 3*5^3 + 3*5^4 + O(5^20))*x^3 + (2*5^2 + 2*5^3 + O(5^20))*x^2 + (5^2 + O(5^20))*x + O(5^20)) of Univariate Polynomial Ring in x over 5-adic Ring with capped relative precision 20
```

Perhaps more troubling,

```
U>=I
False
```

However, I'm not an expert in the implementation of these rings.  However, Sage does give

```
R(37).is_unit()
True
```

On the other hand,

```
K = R.ideal(A(37))
K==U
```

gives `True` but

```
L = R.ideal(1,g1)
L == U
```

gives `False`.

I feel like there must be something obvious I'm missing here, but if so maybe the documentation needs some work, so I've opened [Trac 28692](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/28692).  If we're off base, I'm sure we'll hear - you may also wish to ask on [ask.sagemath](http://ask.sagemath.org) where a lot more devs hang out.

Comment: I see, thanks. I will check the tag and try to ask there as well.